# What does this square bracket and parenthesis bracket notation mean [first1,last1)?

Tags: mathematical-notation

I have seen number ranges represented as `[first1,last1)` and `[first2,last2)`.

I would like to know what such a notation means.

Comment: `[first, last)` is a half-open interval as others have noted. In some textbooks, this is also written as `[first, last>` and has exactly the same meaning, only the syntax is different.

Comment: A better place for this question would be http://math.stackexchange.com/ (IMHO). But never mind! :)

Comment: As a Mnemonic, think the square bracket grabs on to that value, meaning "up to and including".  And the round parenthesis is softer and less restrictive meaning: "up to but not including".

Comment: As a programmer whenever I see square brackets it always gives me a remembrance of Extended Backus-Naur form - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

Comment: I recommend migrating this to math.SE

Comment: Alternative mnemonic, if you put the square brackets back to back in reverse order it looks like a capital I for Inclusive: `][`. Or if you put parenthesis back to back in reverse order it looks like an X for eXclusive: `)(`

Answer (score 335, accepted):

A bracket - `[` or `]` - means that end of the range is **inclusive** -- it includes the element listed. A parenthesis - `(` or `)` - means that end is **exclusive** and doesn't contain the listed element. So for `[first1, last1)`, the range starts with `first1` (and includes it), but ends just before `last1`.

Assuming integers:

- (0, 5) = 1, 2, 3, 4
- (0, 5] = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
- [0, 5) = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
- [0, 5] = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: This evolves from grade school pre-algebra, where you learn about functions f(x) and the function's domain and range, where a function like f(x)=x^2, would have a range of 0 to positive infinity, denoted with [0,∞).

Comment: @Timbo ∞ is not a number.

Comment: @pycoder your definition of number seems unnecessarily limiting.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number

Comment: @Timbo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity If infinity is a number, then it is the only number that I know of such that x / x != 1 and the only number where x / 2 = x (with the exception of 0).

Comment: @pycoder. Almost correct. Try also plugging -∞ and 1/∞ into your equations.  One is the only number I know of such that y * x = y.  Zero, one, infinities, and infinitesimals are unlike other numbers in a number of ways.  Each type of number -- each number -- is unlike all other numbers in a number of ways.  The ancient Greeks didn't think transcendental numbers were numbers.  Imaginary and complex numbers are outside the hyperreal number sets.  When people say "∞ is not a number" they mean "∞ is not a _real_ number" or similar for whatever subset of numbers they want you to work in.

Comment: @Timbo Good point, although I wasn't intending to imply that because infinity has unique qualities, it is not a number. I suppose it depends on the definition of number. My initial comment was a quote that I remember from my Calculus I professor. I hadn't thought to challenge it, and I guess I missed the context he was intending to apply that definition.

Comment: @JakeD Regarding your initial comment, you're right in a way that infinity is not a number, hence why the set [0, ∞) does not include it.

Comment: ∞ isn't an *ordinal* number, of the sort that you can do arithmetic with.  But it's a valid cardinal number when answering questions like "How many integers are there?".  It's also, as in this case, perfectly valid as a *limit*

Answer (score 43):

That's a [half-open interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Excluding_the_endpoints).

- A closed interval `[a,b]` **includes** the end points.
- An open interval `(a,b)` **excludes** them.

In your case the end-point at the start of the interval is included, but the end is excluded. So it means the interval "first1 <= x < last1".

Half-open intervals are useful in programming because they correspond to the common idiom for looping:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { ... }
```

Here i is in the range [0, n).

Answer (score 23):

The concept of *interval notation* comes up in *both* Mathematics and Computer Science.  The Mathematical notation `[`, `]`, `(`, `)` denotes the *domain* (or  *range*) of an interval.

- The brackets `[` and `]` means:

  1. The number is **included**,
  2. This side of the interval is *closed*,
- The parenthesis `(` and `)` means:

  1. The number is **excluded**,
  2. This side of the interval is *open*.

An interval with mixed states is called *"half-open"*.

For example, the range of consecutive integers from 1 .. 10 (inclusive) would be *notated* as such:

- [1,10]

Notice how the word `inclusive` was used. If we want to *exclude* the end point but "cover" the same range we need to move the end-point:

- [1,11)

For both left and right edges of the interval there are actually 4 permutations:

```
(1,10) =   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9       Set has  8 elements
(1,10] =   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10    Set has  9 elements
[1,10) = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9       Set has  9 elements
[1,10] = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10    Set has 10 elements
```

How does this relate to Mathematics and Computer Science?

Array indexes tend to use a *different* offset depending on which field are you in:

- Mathematics tends to be *one*-based.
- Certain programming languages tends to be *zero*-based, such as C, C++, Javascript, Python, while other languages such as Mathematica, Fortran, Pascal are one-based.

These differences can lead to subtle *fence post errors*, aka, [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) bugs when implementing Mathematical algorithms such as for-loops.

## Integers

If we have a set or array, say of the first few primes `[ 2, 3, 5, 7,  11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 ]`, Mathematicians would refer to the first element as the `1st` *absolute*  element. i.e. Using subscript notation to denote the index:

- a<sub>1</sub> = 2
- a<sub>2</sub> = 3
- :
- a<sub>10</sub> = 29

Some programming languages, in contradistinction, would refer to the first element as the `zero'th` *relative* element.

- a[0] = 2
- a[1] = 3
- :
- a[9] = 29

Since the array indexes are in the range [0,N-1] then for clarity purposes it would be "nice" to keep the same numerical value for the range 0 .. N instead of adding textual *noise* such as a `-1` bias.

For example, in C or JavaScript, to iterate over an array of N elements a programmer would write the common idiom of  `i = 0, i < N` with the interval [0,N) instead of the slightly more verbose [0,N-1]:

```js
function main() {
    var output = "";
    var a = [ 2, 3, 5, 7,  11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 ];
    for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) // [0,10)
       output += "[" + i + "]: " + a[i] + "\n";

    if (typeof window === 'undefined') // Node command line
        console.log( output )
    else
        document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
 <html>
     <body onload="main();">
         <pre id="output1"></pre>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Mathematicians, since they start counting at 1, would instead use the `i = 1, i <= N` nomenclature but now we need to correct the array offset in a zero-based language.

e.g.

```js
function main() {
    var output = "";
    var a = [ 2, 3, 5, 7,  11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 ];
    for( var i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) // [1,10]
       output += "[" + i + "]: " + a[i-1] + "\n";

    if (typeof window === 'undefined') // Node command line
        console.log( output )
    else
        document.getElementById( "output2" ).innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body onload="main()";>
        <pre id="output2"></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Aside**:

In programming languages that are 0-based you might need a *kludge* of a dummy zero'th element to use a Mathematical 1-based algorithm. e.g. [Python Index Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623264/python-data-structure-index-start-at-1-instead-of-0)

## Floating-Point

Interval notation is also important for floating-point numbers to avoid subtle bugs.

When dealing with floating-point numbers especially in Computer Graphics (color conversion, computational geometry, animation easing/blending, etc.) often times normalized numbers are used. That is, numbers between 0.0 and 1.0.

It is important to know the edge cases if the endpoints are *inclusive* or *exclusive*:

- (0,1) = 1e-M .. 0.999...
- (0,1] = 1e-M .. 1.0
- [0,1) = 0.0 .. 0.999...
- [0,1] = 0.0 .. 1.0

Where M is some [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).  This is why you might sometimes see `const float EPSILON = 1e-#` idiom in C code (such as `1e-6`) for a 32-bit floating point number. This SO question [Does EPSILON guarantee anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729637/does-epsilon-really-guarantees-anything-in-floating-point-computations) has some preliminary details.  For a more comprehensive answer see `FLT_EPSILON` and David Goldberg's [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Some implementations of a random number generator, `random()` may produce values in the range 0.0 .. 0.999... instead of the more convenient 0.0 .. 1.0.  Proper comments in the code will document this as [0.0,1.0) or [0.0,1.0] so there is no ambiguity as to the usage.

Example:

- You want to generate `random()` colors.  You convert three floating-point values to unsigned 8-bit values to generate a 24-bit pixel with red, green, and blue channels respectively. Depending on the interval output by `random()` you may end up with `near-white` (254,254,254) or `white` (255,255,255).

```
     +--------+-----+
     |random()|Byte |
     |--------|-----|
     |0.999...| 254 | <-- error introduced
     |1.0     | 255 |
     +--------+-----+
```

For more details about floating-point precision and robustness with intervals see Christer Ericson's [Real-Time Collision Detection](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607323), Chapter 11 *Numerical Robustness*, Section 11.3 *Robust Floating-Point Usage*.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a mathematical convention in the definition of an interval where square brackets mean "extremal inclusive" and round brackets "extremal exclusive".