# Cut2 in R (Hmisc) respecting cutpoints

Tags: r

I have a question about the binning of continuous variables by `cut2` from `Hmisc` in `R` and why in some cases the cutpoints are not treated the same.

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349154/using-cut2-from-hmisc-to-calculate-cuts-for-different-number-of-groups), especially the answer from Christopher Bottoms, but it doesnt address my question as to why cut2 doesnt seem to respect the cutpoints supplied to it in certain circumstances.

Given

```
v<-seq(1:12)
v
```

I want to supply a list of cutpoints (a,b,c..,y,z) and have a numeric variable binned into the ranges [-Inf,b), [b,c),...[y,Inf]

This seems to work fine.

```
    cuts<-cut2(v,g = 4,onlycuts = TRUE)
    cuts[1]<- -Inf
    cuts[length(cuts)]<- Inf 
    cuts
    > cuts
    [1] -Inf    4    7   10  Inf

table(cut2(v,cuts = cuts))
> table(cut2(v,cuts = cuts))

[-Inf,   4) [   4,   7) [   7,  10) [  10, Inf] 
          3           3           3           3
```

But not this. How to accomplish a binning based on a user defined rule like this?

```
cuts<-cut2(v,g = 7,onlycuts = TRUE)
cuts[1]<- -Inf
cuts[length(cuts)]<- Inf 
cuts

> cuts
[1] -Inf    3    5    7    8   10  Inf

table(cut2(v,cuts = cuts))

> table(cut2(v,cuts = cuts))

[-Inf,   3) [   3,   5) [   5,   7)           7 [   8,  10) [  10, Inf] 
          2           2           2           1           2           3
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? I'm not sure I see a problem with the output. Are you just confused by the lone 7? Try `table(cut2(v,cuts = cuts, oneval=FALSE))`

Comment: I think that was what I was missing! I will need to test some more but seemed to work!