# Generating random numbers over a range in Go

Tags: random, go

All the integer functions in [`math/rand`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Int) generate non-negative numbers.

```
rand.Int() int              // [0, MaxInt]
rand.Int31() int32          // [0, MaxInt32]
rand.Int31n(n int32) int32  // [0, n)
rand.Int63() int64          // [0, MaxInt64]
rand.Int63n(n int64) int64  // [0, n)
rand.Intn(n int) int        // [0, n)
```

I would like to generate random numbers in the range **[-m, n)**. In other words, I would like to generate a mix of positive and negative numbers.

Comment: Your specification of range may be obvious to you and may be mathematically unambiguous, but most people are heavily attracted by symmetry, so many will think of the interval `[min,max]`. Well, maybe a matter of taste...

Comment: In other words: Your *`mix of positive and negative numbers`* will be unbalanced.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

For Go 1.22+:

Use the [`math/rand/v2`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand/v2) package.

```golang
import "math/rand/v2"

func randRange(min, max int) int {
    return rand.IntN(max-min) + min
}
```

For Go 1.21 and earlier:

```golang
import "math/rand"

func randRange(min, max int) int {
    return rand.Intn(max-min) + min
}
```

Please note that this returns numbers in the range **[min, max)**, meaning that `max` is never returned. For example, `randRange(1, 3)` would return `1` and `2` only. It would never return `3`. If you want numbers in the range **[min, max]**, just add `1` as shown below:

```golang
return rand.IntN(max+1-min) + min
```

Comment: `rand.Intn(2 - 1) + 1` will always return 1

Comment: The question asks for random numbers in the range [min, max). The only number in range [1, 2) is 1.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen range [min, max)

Comment: This is what I was missing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396290/what-does-this-square-bracket-and-parenthesis-bracket-notation-mean-first1-last#:~:text=A%20bracket%20means%20that%20end,but%20ends%20just%20before%20last1%20.

Comment: import "math/rand"

Comment: Deprecated: As of Go 1.20 there is no reason to call Seed with a random value. Programs that call Seed with a known value to get a specific sequence of results should use New(NewSource(seed)) to obtain a local random generator.

Comment: Thank you @IStranger! I've updated my answer to remove the deprecated `rand.Seed()` call.

Answer (score 21):

This will generate random numbers within given range [a, b]

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
n := a + rand.Intn(b-a+1)
```

[source](https://programming.guide/go/generate-number-random-range.html)

Comment: This is the simplest answer that actually gives you the maximum value.

Comment: For clarity a = min and b = max. Maybe obvious to some but it tripped me out

Comment: It's no longer necessary to see the random number generator before calling `rand.Intn`

Answer (score 11):

As to prevent repeating `min` and `max` over and over again, I suggest to switch range and random in thinking about it. This is what I found to work as expected:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

// range specification, note that min <= max
type IntRange struct {
    min, max int
}

// get next random value within the interval including min and max
func (ir *IntRange) NextRandom(r* rand.Rand) int {
    return r.Intn(ir.max - ir.min +1) + ir.min
}

func main() {
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(55))
    ir := IntRange{-1,1}
    for i := 0; i<10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(ir.NextRandom(r))
    }
}
```

[See on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JtMg4jGhxw)

### Specifying the range

The [solution you found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23577092/2932052) in the Cookbook misses to exactly specify how `min` and `max` work, but of course it **meets your specification** (*[-min, max)*). I decided to specify the range as a closed interval (*[-min, max]*, that means its borders are included in the valid range). Compared to my understanding of the Cookbook description:

> gives you that random number within any two positive numbers that you specify (in this case, 1 and 6).

<sub>(which can be found [below the code snippet in the Golang Cookbook](https://golangcookbook.blogspot.de/2012/11/generate-random-number-in-given-range.html))</sub>

the Cookbook implementation is **off by one** (which of course brings it in good company with lots of programs that are helpful at first glance).

Comment: Good catch, @Wolf--I noticed the same issue with the Cookbook example. (This should have more votes, but the upvoters appear to have left SO a long time ago.)

Comment: ...well, you are still here ;) I think that my variation should be understood as a side note because the OP explicitly referred to `the range [-m, n)` which is the understanding of ranges that is most common to programmers, mostly not to users... BTW: isolating the interval *may* be interesting, sometimes helpful, but definitely challenging for good naming: Today, I'm a little bit confused about `IntRange`s that produce `NextRandom` values.

Comment: it returns always the same results https://play.golang.org/p/pXZvtcmxjOq

Comment: @rok The implementation of the go playground fakes the time, see [Inside the Go Playground - The Go Blog](https://blog.golang.org/playground) for the details, so I decided to go that way instead of [*failing on fake randomization*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48360260/2932052)

Answer (score 2):

A small utility I wrote for generating random slices(very much like python range)

Code - https://github.com/alok87/goutils/blob/master/pkg/random/random.go

```
import "github.com/alok87/goutils/pkg/random"
random.RangeInt(2, 100, 5)

[3, 10, 30, 56, 67]
```

Comment: it's always returning the same numbers https://play.golang.org/p/oO6nBlQdWTX

Answer (score 2):

Solution that worked for me is:

`j = rand.Intn(600) - 100`

where **m** is 100 and **n** is 500, it will generate numbers from -100 to 499.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (Generate random number between 1 and 10)...

```
import "math/rand"

rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
randId := rand.Intn(10-1) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using for cycle. For example, you need to generate a number between 50 and 100:

```
val := rand.Intn(100) + 1    // determined the upper bound of the cycle
for val < 50 {
val = rand.Intn(100) + 1}   //   repeat the generation if the number is less than 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Wolf's answer, however I'd add more OOP-alike style like that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Random struct {
    source rand.Source
    mu     sync.Mutex
}

func (rnd *Random) Next(from int, to int) int {
    rnd.mu.Lock()
    if rnd.source == nil {
        rnd.source = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    }
    rnd.mu.Unlock()
    return from + rand.New(rnd.source).Intn(to-from+1)
}

func main() {
    rnd := Random{}
    println(rnd.Next(1, 100))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question asks how to generate random numbers between `min` and `max` where max is not inclusive meaning `max` will never be reached.

For example, if min is 1 and max is 4 then it would only give you values from 1-3.

If you came here looking how to generate all numbers in `min` and `max` range then you need to adjust for that by adding +1.

```
rand.Intn(max + 1 - min) + min
```

Example of it working by showing which numbers were hit and how many times:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    dat := make(map[int]int)
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        x := getRandomInt(1, 4)
        dat[x] += 1
    }

    fmt.Println(dat)
}

func getRandomInt(min, max int) int {
    return rand.Intn(max + 1 - min) + min
}
```

Output:

```
map[1:24810 2:25194 3:25024 4:24972]
```

You can also randomly generate negative numbers. If we made `min` -5 and `max` 5 we get:

Output:

```
map[-5:9302 -4:9121 -3:9136 -2:8951 -1:9116 0:8928 1:9156 2:8970 3:9188 4:9045 5:9087]
```

Comment: You’re correct that max is never reached. The question asks for random numbers in the range `[min, max)`. The `)` means the upper bound is noninclusive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Will update the answer accordingly. Landed here from Google search on random numbers so I think this answer is still helpful for other people looking to include `max` in their range.