# Mock random generator in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go, random

For my tests purpose, I would like to mock random numbers in Go. So I created the Random interface. During unit testing I return the identity function, while for implementation I generate a random number with rand package.

It is the right way for mocking random numbers in Go? Any help appreciated.

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/bibNnmY2t1g

main:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
}

type Random interface {
    Uint(_ uint) uint
}

type rndGenerator func(n uint) uint

type Randomizer struct {
    fn rndGenerator
}

func NewRandomizer(fn rndGenerator) *Randomizer {
    return &Randomizer{fn: fn}
}

func (r *Randomizer) Uint(n uint) uint {
    return r.fn(n)
}

func fakeRand(n uint) uint { return n }
func realRand(_ uint) uint { return uint(rand.Uint64()) }

func main() {
    fakeRnd := NewRandomizer(fakeRand).Uint
    fmt.Println(fakeRnd(1))
    fmt.Println(fakeRnd(2))

    realRnd := NewRandomizer(realRand).Uint
    fmt.Println(realRnd(0))
    fmt.Println(realRnd(0))
}
```

test:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "math/rand"
    "reflect"
)

func TestNewRandomizer(t *testing.T) {
    fn := func(n uint) uint { return n }

    type args struct {
        fn rndGenerator
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want *Randomizer
    }{
        {
            "test",
            args{fn},
            &Randomizer{fn},
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := NewRandomizer(tt.args.fn); reflect.TypeOf(got) != reflect.TypeOf(tt.want) {
                t.Errorf("NewRandomizer() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}

func TestRandomer_Uint(t *testing.T) {
    rnd := uint(rand.Uint64())

    type fields struct {
        fn rndGenerator
    }
    type args struct {
        n uint
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name   string
        fields fields
        args   args
        want   uint
    }{
        {
            "test",
            fields{func(n uint) uint { return n }},
            args{rnd},
            rnd,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            r := &Randomizer{
                fn: tt.fields.fn,
            }
            if got := r.Uint(tt.args.n); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("Randomizer.Uint() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}

func Test_fakeRand(t *testing.T) {
    rnd := uint(rand.Uint64())

    type args struct {
        n uint
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want uint
    }{
        {
            "test",
            args{rnd},
            rnd,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := fakeRand(tt.args.n); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("fakeRand() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}

func Test_realRand(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        in0 uint
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want bool
    }{
        {
            "test",
            args{0},
            true,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := realRand(tt.args.in0); got < 1 {
                t.Errorf("realRand() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of mocking random numbers? (Changing underlying generator? Using third party packages? Or getting a specific sequence for tests?)

Comment: It's for testing purpose. All my structs have a random id in the implementation.

Comment: One of the reasons for using a PRNG is so that the output is repeatable. What is the goal of the mock if the output is already the same each time?

Comment: IT's not the same since I use an identity function where I pass as argument the output I want

Comment: See Go Playground for output examples: https://play.golang.org/p/bibNnmY2t1g

Comment: They are the same for me. Subsequent runs of that example consistently print 961355788 and 217248211. Go Playground always runs the code with the same time (2009-11-10T23:00:00Z), so `rand.Seed` argument is a constant there. So if you don't need a specific sequence but just a deterministic one - there is no real reason to mock.

Comment: play.golang isn't a good place to try things with random numbers. It caches the result of runs, so if you type the same program twice there is a possibility that the response will be fetched from cache instead of being compiled and runned.

Answer (score 0):

Your example makes no real use of the `Random` interface since the mocking is being done at the function field level of the `Randomizer` type.

I would recommend, if possible, to ditch the function field as well as the functions and instead define two separate implementations of the `Random` interface. You can use empty structs for this, they may look weird at first but they have the nice property of taking up 0 bytes of memory.

The main reason for the recommendation is that when you use function fields you lose the ability to compare your struct type values with `reflect.DeepEqual`. This is because two function values are only equal if they have the same type *and both are nil*.

As an example let's first look at your `TestNewRandomizer` which is a symptom of the issue stated above. In the test you're just comparing the type of the return value which is something already ensured by the compiler, so the test is absolutely pointless.

Now, let's say you drop the test, since it's useless, but for some reason you keep the function field. Because of this any struct type that depends on `*Randomizer` will also be untestable with `DeepEqual` and you'll have the same difficulties when trying to come up with a test for that type.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
}

type Random interface {
    Uint(_ uint) uint
}

type Randomizer struct {}

func NewRandomizer() Randomizer {
    return Randomizer{}
}

func (r Randomizer) Uint(n uint) uint {
    return uint(rand.Uint64())
}

type FakeRandomizer struct {}

func NewFakeRandomizer() FakeRandomizer {
    return FakeRandomizer{}
}

func (r FakeRandomizer) Uint(n uint) uint {
    return n
}

func main() {
    fakeRnd := NewFakeRandomizer().Uint
    fmt.Println(fakeRnd(1))
    fmt.Println(fakeRnd(2))

    realRnd := NewRandomizer().Uint
    fmt.Println(realRnd(0))
    fmt.Println(realRnd(0))
}
```

Note that i'm intentionally returning values instead of pointers since empty structs are smaller than pointers.

Comment: Many Thanks. I borrowed your code and changed the Random method signature to get rid of the function argument: https://play.golang.org/p/w2iKC1Dz0Ek .

Comment: @SofianeCherchalli it's better to have your `StudentManager` depend on the interface `Random` instead of the concrete type `Randomizer`, that way when you write tests for `NewStudent` you can mock `rnd`. https://play.golang.org/p/vibEizUH7Bg

Comment: Sorry it was a typo error at midnight. I meant Random :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a method which generates a random integer and returns `true` if the integer is less than or equal to 50 and `false` if the integer is greater than 50 in the range [0, 100).

This is how I have created my structures to mock the functionality:

```
type Decider struct {
    RandImpl func(int) int
}

func (d *Decider) Decide(randRange int) bool {
    randVal := d.RandImpl(randRange)
    log.Info("RandVal: ", randVal)
    if randVal <= 50 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I'm calling this method in this manner:

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
decider := decide.Decider{
    RandImpl: func(x int) int { return rand.Intn(x) },
}
decider.Decide(100)
```

In my `_test.go` file, I have this:

```
decider := Decider{
    RandImpl: func(x int) int { return 42 },
}
ret := decider.Decide(100)
assert.True(t, ret)
```

This way you can mock the functionality of the random number generator.