# How do you make a list inclusive?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to create a list from 1 to 52 inclusive. (E.g. for a deck of cards) I was just wondering how do you make a list inclusive?

I know how to make a list, just am not sure how to make it inclusive. I searched on here for awhile and couldn't really find anything helpful.

Comment: Inclusive means, in this case, that it includes 1 and 52, and all numbers in between.

Comment: You know how to make a list, so why not make one and show us what's wrong with your list, after researching what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create list with `[0,51]` values

```
list_of_cards = [i for i in range(52)]
```

This will create list with `[1,52]` values (This is what you want to use):

```
list_of_cards = [i for i in range(1,53)]
```

Comment: Good use of list comprehension. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why *list comprehension* when range itself returns list?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri:  range returns a list only in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x it returns a range object, which is more like a generator than a list in that it takes less memory. It can be converted to a list with `list(range(1,53))` or a list comprehension. (The tag in the OP is Python 3.x.)

Answer (score 5):

Inclusive is a term that is often used when expressing bounds. It means that the range of this bound includes all values **including** the inclusive value. An example of this would be:

*Print all integers 1-5 inclusive.* 
The expected output would be:

1 2 3 4 5

The antonym of this term would be exclusive which would include all values **excluding** the exclusive value. An example of this would be:

*Print all integers 1-5 exclusive.* 
The expected output would be:

1 2 3 4

It is important to note, that in programming generally the first value is  inclusive unless otherwise noted. In mathematics this can differ. Inclusive and exclusive ranges are often denoted with [] and ().

[What does this square bracket and parenthesis bracket notation mean [first1,last1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396290/what-does-this-square-bracket-and-parenthesis-bracket-notation-mean-first1-last)