# custom break and using cut function in R

Tags: r

I will like to group some data into several categories for boxplot in R. I obtained my groups like this:

```
cut(60:95, breaks = c(60,64,68,72,76,80,85,90,95))
```

Here's my output:

```
(60,64] (60,64] (60,64] (60,64] (64,68] (64,68] (64,68] (64,68] 
(68,72] (68,72] (68,72] (68,72] (72,76] (72,76] (72,76]
(72,76] (76,80] (76,80] (76,80] (76,80] (80,85] (80,85] (80,85] (80,85] 
(80,85] (85,90] (85,90] (85,90] (85,90] (85,90] (90,95]
(90,95] (90,95] (90,95] (90,95]
```

But the categories that I would actually like to have are:

```
(60,64] (60,64] (60,64] (60,64] (65,68] (65,68] (65,68] (65,68] etc
```

Does anyone know how I can get my desired outputs?

Comment: So you do not want 65 to be within any intervall at all? Or what is the essential difference between the standard function's result and the result you want to get?

Comment: To add to @Bernhard's question, what about the interval `(64, 65]`? Or will the values be always integers? BTW, the first value, `60` is not an element of the first interval, so `cut` gives `NA`. If you use `include.lowest = TRUE` the problem seems to be solved, then it is just a matter of factor labels.

Comment: The symbols in `(60,64]` are not arbitrary. `(` means include the value in the bin. `]` means exclude the value in the bin.

Comment: I have a `NA` as the first element. However, it seems that you want either 64 or 65 to be in the `(65, 68]` range. If you want that, you are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limits (inf and sup)

```
breaks_lim_inf<-c(60,65,69,73,77,81,86,91)
breaks_lim_sup<-c(64,68,72,76,80,85,90,95)
```

I build the breaks

```
list_int_unique<-as.factor(paste0("(",breaks_lim_inf,",",breaks_lim_sup,"]"))
list_int_unique
[1] (60,64] (65,68] (69,72] (73,76] (77,80] (81,85] (86,90] (91,95]
Levels: (60,64] (65,68] (69,72] (73,76] (77,80] (81,85] (86,90] (91,95]
```

I replicate breaks on the numbers between 60 and 95

```
list<-seq(60,95)
list_int<-list_int_unique[findInterval(list,breaks_lim_inf)]
list_int
```

Your Output

```
 [1] (60,64] (60,64] (60,64] (60,64] (60,64] (65,68] (65,68] (65,68] (65,68] (69,72] (69,72] (69,72] (69,72] (73,76] (73,76]
[16] (73,76] (73,76] (77,80] (77,80] (77,80] (77,80] (81,85] (81,85] (81,85] (81,85] (81,85] (86,90] (86,90] (86,90] (86,90]
[31] (86,90] (91,95] (91,95] (91,95] (91,95] (91,95]
Levels: (60,64] (65,68] (69,72] (73,76] (77,80] (81,85] (86,90] (91,95]
```

The use of "(" and "]" are unconventional, I suggest to read this [SO Question](http://I'm%20with%20you,%20I%20suggest%20to%20Rob%20to%20read%20this%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396290/what-does-this-square-bracket-and-parenthesis-bracket-notation-mean-first1-last%20to%20better%20understand%20the%20use%20of) to better understand the use of "(" and "]"

Comment: While this might answer to OP's question, it should be stressed that decoding 65 as belonging to the `(65,68]` range is quite bizarre.

Comment: I'm with you, I suggest to Rob to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396290/what-does-this-square-bracket-and-parenthesis-bracket-notation-mean-first1-last to better understand the use of "(" and "]"

Comment: Apologies for getting back late! Thanks so much @Terru_theTerror. It works as expected and I know more now about those notations.