# What does "[ptr, ptr+len) must be a valid range" mean?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer

In various places in the c++ Standard, the phrase:

*Requires:* `[p, p + len)` is a valid range.

(where p is a pointer, and `len` is a number) is used.

An alternate version for iterators is:

*Requires:* `[first, last)` is a valid range.

What does this mean?

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What don't you understand?

Comment: Hrm. I looked for this question, and didn't find the dups. Other people are better at searching than me. I had an answer ready to go, too.

Comment: These are pretty bad dupe targets that completely missed the "is a valid range" part. Reopening.

Comment: "valid" means ranges that you are allowed to access, not causing UB.

Comment: If the confusion is with regard to the interval notation then [this is a possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396290/what-does-this-square-bracket-and-parenthesis-bracket-notation-mean-first1-last).

Comment: @SombreroChicken and "allowed" are all those that are valid....

Comment: @user463035818 No, allowed are those that do not cause UB, read my comment again.

Answer (score 4):

I think the relevant part of the `C++17` Standard is here

> **27.2.1** In general **[** iterator.requirements.general **]**
>
> ...
>
> **8** An iterator `j` is called ***reachable*** from an iterator `i` if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression `++i` that makes `i == j`. If `j` is ***reachable*** from `i`, they refer to elements of the same sequence.
>
> **9** Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data structures have interfaces that use ranges. A range is a pair of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation. A range `[i, i)` is an empty range; in general, a range `[i, j)` refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the element pointed to by `i` and up to but not including the element pointed to by `j`. Range `[i, j)` is valid if and only if `j` is reachable from `i`. The result of the application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is undefined.

So extracting the pertinent parts:

> **8** An iterator `j` is called ***reachable*** from an iterator `i` if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression `++i` that makes `i == j`...
>
> **9** ... Range `[i, j)` is valid if and only if `j` is reachable from `i`....

So it seems that a "valid range" is a pair of *iterators* that belong to the **same container** (or array), with `j` being farther along than `i`.

But also not forgetting:

> in general, a range `[i, j)` refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the element pointed to by `i` and up to but not including the element pointed to by `j`.

So all of the *iterators* between `i` and `j` (but not necessarily including `j`) **must** be "in the data structure" *(ie. not out-of-bounds)*.

Comment: Is `[nullptr, nullptr)` a valid range?

Comment: @ceztko That is a very good question. IMO yes it is based on  paragraph`8` quoted in my answer: _"An iterator j is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression ++i that makes i == j"._ In this case, the "finate sequence of applications" is _zero._

Comment: On a couple of wild tests, the Microsoft STL implementation agrees, `[nullptr, nullptr)` is a valid range. For example `string(nullptr, 0)` or `string_view(nullptr, 0)`.

Comment: @ceztko Actually those look fine according to my understanding of [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

Answer (score 1):

What this means is that everything between `first` **inclusively** and `p+len` or `last` **exclusively** must be valid.

This all hinges on the fact that C++ allows for past-the-end of arrays pointers to exist, as long as you only use them to refer to the "end" of the array without ever dereferencing them.

So If I have:

```
int my_array[10];

int* first = &my_array[0];
int* last = &my_array[10];
```

Then `first` and `last` represent a valid range, even if `last` technically points to nowhere valid.

The same principle applies to iterators, where the `end()` of a container is not actually part of the container's data at all.

This all may look fairly bizarre at first glance, but this way of representing ranges allows for dealing with empty ranges in a sane way.

Comment: What this also means is that you can form a range around a variable: `int a; int* begin = &a; int* end = &a + 1;` :)