# Create a sequence of number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I revised my clarification.
Considering the search value as 300 and as per the below data already available in table

- (30000, 80000)--300 will fit(30000-80000=50000) where 300 sequence of numbers are available
- (700, 4000) --300 will fit (700-4000=3300) where 300 sequence numbers are available
- (9000, 120000)--300 will fit(9000-12000=3000) where 300 sequence numbers are available
- (100, 600)--300 will fit (100-600=500) where 300 sequence numbers are available and it should create a block based on this and update this entry
- (4000, 5500)--300 will fit (4000-5500=1500) where 300 sequence numbers are available

it should create a new entry and update the existing block where the search value fits

```
(30000, 80000) 
(700, 4000)
(9000, 120000)
(300, 600) - Updated the existing entry (100, 600)
(4000,5500)
(100,300) - created a new entry for 300 blocks
```

Once again if the search value is 500 on the same table

- (30000, 80000)--500 will fit here because 30000 - 80000 = 50000 where 500 sequence of numbers are available
- (700, 4000)--500 will fit here because 700-4000 = 3300 where 500 sequence numbers are available and here it has to create the block because this is the least available block to fit 500
- (9000, 120000)--500 will fit here because 9000 - 12000 = 300 where 500 sequence of numbers are available
- (300, 600) --500 will not fit here 300-600=300 where 500 sequence numbers is not available
- (4000,5500)--500 will fit here 4000-55000=1500 where 500 sequence numbers are available but it should not create the block based on this row.- As 500 will fit in (700, 4000)
- (100,300) --500 will no fit here 100-300 where 500 sequence number is not available

it should create a new entry and update the existing block where the search value fits

```
(30000, 80000)
(1200, 4000)- Updated the existing entry (700, 4000)
(9000, 120000)
(300, 600) 
(4000,5500)
(100,300) 
(700, 1200)- created a new entry for 500 blocks
```

Please ignore the blow...

I am working on creating sequence of numbers to be generated and update the table(SQL Server). Could you please guide me on how to write a query for this scenario/logic

Table Name: NumberBlocks

| A | B | For my understanding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30000 | 80000 | 300 and 5000 will fit here |
| 700 | 4000 | 300 will fit but not 5000 |
| 9000 | 120000 | 300 will fit but not 5000 |
| 150000 | 250000 | 300 and 5000 will fit here |
| 100 | 600 | 300 will fit but not 5000 |

1. If user is asking 300 number sequence then it will check the table and find the 300 will fit in which row. In this case 300 will fit in all the cases but it should 1st check the least block and update and create a new entry
2. If user is asking 5000 number sequence then it will check the table and find the 5000 will fit in which row. In this case 5000 will fit in all the cases but it should 1st check the least block and update and create a new entry

| A | B | For my understanding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30000 | 80000 |  |
| 700 | 4000 |  |
| 9000 | 120000 |  |
| 150000 | 250000 |  |
| 100 | 200 | Earlier it was 100 and 600, now it is updated as 100 and 200 |
| 300 | 600 | Create a new row 300 and 600 |

I am using Max() and Min() of the table but it will only take what is the max.

Comment: I'm sorry, even with your wording, I'm not following on what you expect the outcome to be.

Comment: What Database Management System? See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: "...In this case 5000 will fit in all the cases...", how? What is the logic here? Like how 5000 matches with row with A = 100 and B = 200.

Comment: So as 300 is in 100-600, you want to split this row into 100-200 and 300-600. This means that you are only dealing with hundreds, right? You don't want this to become 100-299, because all numbers must be multiples of 100. Yes? That will be one insert and one update. We must know your DBMS in order to know how to deal with this task in your DBMS.

Comment: And Dewa Manandhar is right, you have mistakenly copied the 300's decription. I suppose as 5000 has no match, you want to ignore it? Or what else shall be done with the 5000?

Comment: Hi @QuestionGuyBob, Thanks. I just updated what the outcome has to be in 2nd tabular  column. Thanks.

Comment: @KarB Can you clarify exactly what "fit" means? For {100, 600} it makes sense that 300 "fits" and 5000 does not. But how does 5000 fit {9000, 120000}? And how do they both fit {150000, 250000}? I'm trying to read it as columns A and B are intervals, and fit means the value falls between that interval. But that does not track with the example data.

Comment: Hi @Error_2646, We have a block of numbers like 100 to 600, 700 to 4000, 9000 to 12000. If user asking a block of 300 numbers, it means the block 100 to 600(it has 500 blocks) can accommodate 300 numbers. Also 700 to 4000(it has 3330 blocks) can accommodate 300 numbers. In this scenario, if user asks 300 blocks it should take the block 100-600 and create a new block as 100 to 300 and update the block 100 to 600 as 400 to 600.  Thanks

Comment: If the user is asking for example 5000 blocks, it will fit into the available blocks 30000 to 80000,15000 to 25000. Here, the user requested 5000 blocks. So it should create the block based on 15000 to 25000 and create a new record as 15000 to 20000 and update the block 15000 to 25000 to 20000 to 25000. Thanks.

Comment: @KarB Gotcha, makes sense. So if x <= (column_b - column_a), it fits. If x > (column_b - column_a) it does not fit?

Comment: @KarB So of the matches you get on x, take the one with lowest value of column_a. Generate a record which has column_a = (original value of column_b - x). And update the existing match record to column_b = (original value of column_b - x - 100)?

Comment: @KarB That is doable. But as others have said, tag your DBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc...) The syntax will vary.

Comment: Which version of SQL server? Run the command `select @@version;` and post back the first line of the results.

Comment: In your example scenario, the range 100-600 was split into 100-200 and 300-600. What happened to 201-199?  Also, is the range-end inclusive or exclusive? If inclusive, the range `[100, 200]` represents 101 values. If exclusive, the range `[100, 200)` represents 100 values, with the last value being 199. Precision is key to avoiding off-by-one logic errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the details of your 17:53:29Z post and your 21:09:02Z question updates, the range-end value appears to be *exclusive*, so we are dealing with [*half-open intervals*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396290/). These are common in computer science and actually make some aspects of the range allocation logic simpler.

Since we are storing unallocated and allocated ranges in the same table, we will need an IsAllocated flag. Otherwise, repeated requests for the same size allocation will repeatedly allocate the same range. I have also taken the liberty of renaming the columns to something more meaningful to make the code easier to follow.

The following will find lowest available block of sufficient size and (if found) will either allocate the entire range or split the range into allocated and residual unallocated parts. If the requested range is greater than the largest available block size or is <= 0, no block is allocated and a null result is returned,

```
DECLARE @Requested INT = 200

-- Find lowest available block of sufficient size
DECLARE @SelectedStart INT
DECLARE @SelectedEnd INT

SELECT TOP 1 @SelectedStart = SequenceStart, @SelectedEnd = SequenceEndExclusive
FROM Sequences
WHERE SequenceEndExclusive - SequenceStart >= @Requested
AND IsAllocated = 0
AND @Requested > 0  -- Sanity check
ORDER BY SequenceStart

-- If found, either allocate the entire range or split the range into
-- allocated and residual unallocated parts
IF @SelectedStart IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF (@SelectedEnd - @SelectedStart = @Requested)
    BEGIN
        -- Allocate entire range
        UPDATE Sequences
        SET IsAllocated = 1, Notes = 'Allocated entire range'
        WHERE SequenceStart = @SelectedStart
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        -- Update existing range to reflect residual portion
        UPDATE Sequences
        SET SequenceStart = SequenceStart + @Requested, Notes = 'Residual'
        WHERE SequenceStart = @SelectedStart

        -- Insert new allocated range
        INSERT Sequences (SequenceStart, SequenceEndExclusive, IsAllocated, Notes)
        VALUES (@SelectedStart, @SelectedStart + @Requested, 1, 'Added and Allocated')
    END
END

-- Show Results
SELECT @Requested AS Requested, @SelectedStart AS AllocatedStart
SELECT * FROM Sequences
```

(The `Notes` logic and `SELECT * FROM Sequences` are present for demo purposes and can be removed prior to actual use.)

Sample results:

| Requested | AllocatedStart |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 100 |

| SequenceId | SequenceStart | SequenceEndExclusive | IsAllocated | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30000 | 80000 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 700 | 4000 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 9000 | 120000 | 0 |  |
| 4 | 300 | 600 | 0 | Residual |
| 5 | 4000 | 5500 | 0 |  |
| 6 | 100 | 300 | 1 | Added and Allocated |

| Requested | AllocatedStart |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 700 |

| SequenceId | SequenceStart | SequenceEndExclusive | IsAllocated | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30000 | 80000 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 1200 | 4000 | 0 | Residual |
| 3 | 9000 | 120000 | 0 |  |
| 4 | 300 | 600 | 0 |  |
| 5 | 4000 | 5500 | 0 |  |
| 6 | 100 | 300 | 1 |  |
| 7 | 700 | 1200 | 1 | Added and Allocated |

| Requested | AllocatedStart |
| --- | --- |
| 300 | 300 |

| SequenceId | SequenceStart | SequenceEndExclusive | IsAllocated | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30000 | 80000 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 1200 | 4000 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 9000 | 120000 | 0 |  |
| 4 | 300 | 600 | 1 | Allocated entire range |
| 5 | 4000 | 5500 | 0 |  |
| 6 | 100 | 300 | 1 |  |
| 7 | 700 | 1200 | 1 |  |

| Requested | AllocatedStart |
| --- | --- |
| 1000000000 | *null* |

| Requested | AllocatedStart |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | *null* |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mTD4wbnW) for a demo.

There might also be a need for a deallocation mechanism. That could simply set IsAllocated to 0, but should likely also include cleanup logic for merging adjacent (preceding and/or following) unallocated ranges.

Comment: @KarB - I have updated this answer with the latest sample data and scenarios. The results match your posted scenarios with one exception: The first allocation is for 200, not 300.

Comment: Hi @error_2646, The query that you provided works as expected and i am able to created the sequence of numbers based the available ranges. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi @T N, Thanks for the query. It works as expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly, there may be an argument that a temp table with a separate insert and update is cleaner than shoving it all in to one merge.

This assumes that at all points column_a will be unique, and that to avoid overlapping intervals we decrement by 100.

Note - Uses a declared variable for the search parameter. Your exact syntax will vary based on how these queries are coming in.

Steps:

1.) Find the records where x < (column_b - column_a)

2.) Of those, get the earliest by column_a

3.) The first Union clause is what you will insert with the new derived value of column_a

4.) The second Union clause is what you will update with the new derived value of column_b

https://dbfiddle.uk/C6M69gMD

```
create table some_test_data
  (
    column_a integer,
    column_b integer
  );

insert into some_test_data values (30000, 80000);
insert into some_test_data values (700, 4000);
insert into some_test_data values (9000, 120000);
insert into some_test_data values (150000, 250000);
insert into some_test_data values (100, 600);

DECLARE @some_search_value INT;
SET @some_search_value = 5000;
with filtered_match as (
  select
    *
  from
    (
      select
        *,
        column_b - @some_search_value as new_column_a,
        column_b as new_column_b,
        row_number() over (
          partition by 1
          order by
            column_a asc
        ) rn
      from
        some_test_data
      where
        @some_search_value <= column_b - column_a
    ) t
  where
    rn = 1
),
combine_for_single_upsert as (
  -- This will not match the original row for insert
  select *
    from filtered_match
   union
  -- This will match this original row for update
  select column_a,
         column_b,
         column_a as new_column_a,
         column_b - @some_search_value - 100 as new_column_b,
         0
    from filtered_match
)
merge into some_test_data tgt using (
  select
    *
  from
    combine_for_single_upsert
) as mrg on (
  tgt.column_a = mrg.new_column_a
)
when matched then
update
set
  tgt.column_b = (mrg.new_column_b)
  when not matched then
insert
values
  (mrg.new_column_a, mrg.column_b);
```

**Edit:** Separate update and inserts are probably much easier to read.

https://dbfiddle.uk/V7-kdrah

```
DECLARE @some_search_value INT;
SET @some_search_value = 300;
SELECT * 
  INTO #TempForUpsert
  from
    (
      select
        *,
        column_b - @some_search_value as new_column_a_for_new,
        column_b - @some_search_value - 100 new_column_b_for_orig,
        row_number() over (
          partition by 1
          order by
            column_a asc
        ) rn
      from
        some_test_data
      where
        @some_search_value <= column_b - column_a
    ) t
  where
    rn = 1;

update some_test_data
   set some_test_data.column_b = #TempForUpsert.new_column_b_for_orig
  from #TempForUpsert
 where some_test_data.column_a = #TempForUpsert.column_a;

insert into some_test_data
  select new_column_a_for_new,
         column_b
    from #TempForUpsert;

select * 
  from some_test_data
 order
    by column_a,
       column_b;
```

Comment: Hi @Error_2646  If the search value is 300 
(30000, 80000)--300 will fit(30000-80000=50000) where 300 numbers are available(700, 4000) --300 will fit (700-4000=3300) where 300 numbers are available 
(9000, 120000)--300 will fit(9000-12000=3000) where 300  numbers are available 
(100, 600)--300 will fit (100-600=500) where 300  numbers are available and it should create a block based on this and update this entry
(30000, 80000) 
(700, 4000)
(9000, 120000)
(300, 600) - Updated the existing entry (100, 600)
(100,300) - created a new entry for 300 blocks

Comment: Hi @Error_2646Once again if the search value is 500


it should create a new entry and update the existing block like below
(30000, 80000)
(1200, 4000)- Updated the existing entry (700, 4000)
(9000, 120000)
(300, 600) 
(100,300) 
(700, 1200)- created a new entry for 500 blocks

Comment: Hey @KarB is that fully reflected in your sample data? If not, please update the expected result so that it totally captures what you want to see. This answer's output matches that to tee. From this "1st check the least block and update and create a new entry" I was figuring you only want to match the least in case of multiple matches.

Comment: H1 @error_2646 1St Search Value = 300
Available Data

30000-80000
700-4000
9000-120000
150000-250000
100-600

Updated Table
30000-80000
700-4000
9000-120000
150000-250000
400-600
100-400
Once again the search value is 500 on the same table
30000-80000
700-4000
9000-120000
150000-250000
400-600
100-400

Updated Table
30000-80000
1200-4000
9000-120000
150000-250000
400-600
100-400
700-1200

Comment: @KarB Are you sure you are being very careful with this sample data? This does not match what you have in the question. Where for a search value of 300, {100-600} becomes {100,200} and {300, 600}. Note the 100 integer gap between the column B values. But then here you've provided that for 300, {100-600} becomes {100,400} and {400, 600}

Comment: @KarB This answer matches the sample input and output in the question body. The data in this comment is different. If the original question has a typo, please edit it there. Sample data is the life blood of data questions. It must be accurate or else there is no way the answer can be.

Comment: Hi @error_2646, i update the input and output in the body section. Thanks.

Comment: @KarB Please, please ... please (please). Format what you've added to the question. Look at how much more readable the two tables in your question are. It should be a formatted tabular grid of the original. And a formatted tabular grid of what you want to see after the operation.